# Is the transformation $T(v) = v_1v_2$ where $v = (v_1,v_2)$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My answer is no, but the book says yes. It doesn't satisfy the scalar multiplication condition, i.e., the given transformation doesn't satisfy: $T(c \cdot v) = c \cdot T(v)$

My reasoning:
$$T\left(c \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}\right) = T\left( \begin{bmatrix}
c \cdot v_1\\
c \cdot v_2
\end{bmatrix}\right) = (c \cdot v_1) \cdot (c \cdot v_2) = c^2 ( v_1 \cdot v_2) = c^2 \cdot T(v)\neq c \cdot T(v)$$

Thus the given transformation is not linear.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the book. You're right. Linear map is $T(v)=v_1+v_2$.

Comment: You are correct, $T$ is not a linear transformation. Most likely, there is a typographical error in the book you are reading.

Comment: You are, of course, correct in identifying it as non-linear. Just a small nitpick: it’s better to appeal to a concrete counterexample. After all, the assertion $c^2 \cdot T(v) \neq c \cdot T(v)$ is occasionally false, depending on the values of $c$ and $T(v)$. Writing a concrete counterexample where this inequality definitely holds true eliminates this small issue.

Comment: @TheoBendit No explicit counterexample will exist in the case where the field is $\mathbb{F}_2$. So it's actually better (I think) to argue so: $1=T(1,1)=T(1,0)+T(0,1)=0+0=0$ which is always a contradiction in a field.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct; the map is not linear. It must be a typo or error of some kind in the book.